# Request not addressed by spring controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have configured in following way that spring MVC app using **Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE**

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/context/*-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>   
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/cgi/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

**springmvc-servlet.xml**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.pokuri.mvc.controllers"/>
```

**UserController.java**

```
package com.pokuri.mvc.controllers;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String defaultRequest(){
        return "It's a default handler method";
    }   

}
```

**index.jsp**

```
<a class="action" href="cgi/user">Default Action</a>
```

**Sever log on initializing springmvc app:**

```
23:53:04,406 INFO  [DispatcherServlet] FrameworkServlet 'springmvc': initialization started
23:53:04,468 INFO  [XmlWebApplicationContext] Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'springmvc-servlet': startup date [Thu Jun 28 23:53:04 IST 2012]; root of context hierarchy
23:53:04,609 INFO  [XmlBeanDefinitionReader] Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context/services-context.xml]
23:53:04,890 INFO  [DefaultListableBeanFactory] Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@6c4fe: defining beans [dummyService]; root of factory hierarchy
23:53:05,156 INFO  [DispatcherServlet] FrameworkServlet 'springmvc': initialization completed in 750 ms
.....
.....
23:56:17,875 WARN  [PageNotFound] No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/springmvc/cgi/user] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springmvc'
```

When I click on that link in index.jsp, I am getting 404 error. I thing I might have done a silly mistake. But, not able to track it. Can someone help me in this?

Comment: Try putting `@RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.GET)` on `defaultRequest()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your DispatcherServlet is looking for config files ending in `-context.xml`. But your Spring config file is called `springmvc-servlet.xml`.

Comment: that DispacherServlet builds it's WebApplicationContext based on the name given in web.xml(i.e springmvc-servlet.xml). Then I am using that contextConfigLocation to config application context for services, dao and other beans. is it my wrong perception?

Comment: Have you tried changing that line in web.xml to `/WEB-INF/context/*-servlet.xml` (assuming springmvc-servlet.xml is in the context directory)?